# Upgrading 7 Embedded to SP1

Tags: windows-update, embedded, service-pack, windows-embedded-7

I have approximately 100 devices out in the field with Windows 7 Embedded installed. I have a requirement to upgrade the IE version to a newer version (10 or 11), for this I need to update the deployed units to SP1.

The MS page below indicates this is possible. 
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/gg675630(v=WinEmbedded.60).aspx)

It however requires the SP1 CAB file.

I have hunted everywhere I know of to locate this SP1 CAB file but have been unsuccessful. Our embedded license vendors are not any help. 
The SP1 toolkit doesn't appear to have it in either.

I cannot reimage every unit with a new build, this isn't practical for our situation, I need to update the units in the field.

Can anyone advise where I can obtain the CAB file from so I can update the existing installations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same question and eventually found the answer.

The image file needed is X17-48538.img available from the Microsoft OEM site.

It contains:

1. readme.txt              2/26/2011   1204
2. windows6.1-KB976902-X86-Wave0.cab   2/26/2011   4532924
3. windows6.1-KB976902-X86-Wave1.cab   2/26/2011   4531728
4. windows6.1-KB976932-X86-Wave0.cab   2/26/2011   354704066
5. windows6.1-KB976932-X86-Wave1.cab   2/26/2011   541001258

You should be able to get it through your OEM if you don't have direct access to the MyOEM site.