# How to do offline update of Windows Embedded Standard 7 to Service Pack 1

Tags: patch, windows-embedded-7

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to install Service Pack 1 and update a Windows Embedded Standard 7 (WES7) machine that are not connected to any network.

I haven't found much documentation online about this. The article [Update a Device to Standard 7 SP1 (Standard 7 SP1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/gg675630(v=WinEmbedded.60).aspx) seems to be everything from Microsoft.

It seems straight forward, just use DISM as follows:

```
DISM  /online /add-package /PackagePath: <cab_file_name>
```

But where do I find a cab-file for WES7 Sp1?

And then it is updates. What is the best way to download and the copy and install all WES7 on a standalone machine?

What am I not getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading 7 Embedded to SP1](http://superuser.com/questions/906708/upgrading-7-embedded-to-sp1)